# Supabase-Flutter Login verification error "User is not found" but the user is clearly in the database table

Tags: flutter, dart, supabase, supabase-database, supabase-flutter

I've run into a problem where the app says 'User not found. Please check credentials.' although the credentials used is for user in the profiles user_profiles table. Is this because response of the query to the database is a list, or something else? I've also tried adding the .single() command and got the error

```
"Login failed: PostgrestException(message: JSON object requested, multiple (or no) rows returned, code: PGRST116, details: The result contains 0 rows, hint: null)"
```

I've attached the image of the user_profiles table in the database.

supabase database user_profiles table:

[image]

Main file

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:supabase_flutter/supabase_flutter.dart';

class CustomLoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomLoginPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomLoginPageState createState() => _CustomLoginPageState();
}

class _CustomLoginPageState extends State<CustomLoginPage> {
  final TextEditingController _firstNameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _lastNameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _idNumberController = TextEditingController();
  bool _isLoading = false;

  Future<void> _signIn() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });

    final client = Supabase.instance.client;
    try {
      final response = await client
          .from('user_profile')
          .select()
          .eq('first_name', _firstNameController.text.trim())
          .eq('last_name', _lastNameController.text.trim())
          .eq('id_number', _idNumberController.text.trim())
          //.single();

      if (response.isNotEmpty) {
        // Handle successful authentication.
        if (context.mounted) {
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/account');
        }
      } else {
        // Handle user not found.
        if (context.mounted) {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            const SnackBar(
              content: Text('User not found. Please check your credentials.'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            ),
          );
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      if (context.mounted) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text('Login failed: ${err.toString()}'),
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error,
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    if (context.mounted) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }



  void _showSnackBar(String message) {
    if (mounted) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text(message),
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error,
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _firstNameController.dispose();
    _lastNameController.dispose();
    _idNumberController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Custom Sign In')),
      body: ListView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            controller: _firstNameController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'First Name'),
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: _lastNameController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Last Name'),
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: _idNumberController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'ID Number'),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: _isLoading ? null : _signIn,
            child: Text(_isLoading ? 'Loading...' : 'Sign In'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The app should be able to read the user_profiles table and if there is a row that matches the login credentials, then sign in should be successful and the user should be directed to the account page.

Comment: It's either the user does not have permission to query the table because of RLS configurations, or you have a mismatch between the values you are passing to the `eq` filters and the values stored in the table. Perform a `select()` without any filters to verify that the user has permission to query the table, and then try to run the query with hard-coded values so that they match exactly the values stored on the table. Remember, with `eq` filters, capitalization matters.